# Array Adapter overload method

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to add a `ListView` on my `DialogFragment`, but I am getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inside a [DialogFragment](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.DialogFragment/) and you're trying to pass it as the first argument of your Adapter. It, however, expects a `Context` instead of a fragment, hence the error.

You should replace the `this` in your Adapter's constructor with `Activity`, the property of your adapter that contains and Activiy (which is a [Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android))

Answer (score 1):

You are inside a fragment so you need to use the fragments `Activity` property.